# mysql join table, return only rows based on timestamp comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a mysql database like: (simplified to make my point)

```
PARENT
ID | EXPIRE | ITEM
0  | 1000   | FOO
1  | 2000   | BAR
```

And a another with a one to many relationship with table A

```
ITEMS
    ID | FK | TIMESTAMP 
    0  | 0  | 1488555058 
    1  | 0  | 1488555059
    2  | 0  | 1488555060
```

Consider the ITEMS table is being continuously populated with new values with the current timestamp.  I want to query the db and only return records in which The ITEMS table does not contain a record with a TIMESTAMP >= CURRENT_TIME - EXPIRE_TIME - so the result will only be PARENTs that have not received a new ITEM since the EXPIRE time lapsed.

I wrote this which doesn't work:

```
   select P.ID
    from PARENT as P
    JOIN     ITEMS as I
    ON       I.FX =
             (
             SELECT  I2.FK
             FROM    ITEMS as I2
             WHERE   P.ID = I2.FK
             AND  ((((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()* 1000) - I2.TIMESTAMP)))  > P.EXPIRE
             ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
             limit 1
             )
```

What I want is zero rows returned if every PARENT as an ITEM with a TIMESTAMP > than (UNIX_TIMESTAMP - EXPIRE) and a single record for each ITEM without one.

Stuck - any help would be appreciated!

EDIT - based on the answer below this is the working query - what i needed here was a result that contains items that didn't not have an item *newer* than the expire time and to flag them for batch processing.

```
UPDATE PARENT P
SET BATCHID = ?
where not exists(
    select 1 from ITEMS V
    WHERE   V.FK = P.ID
    AND ((((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() * 1000) -  V.TIMESTAMP) / 1000) < P.EXPIRE)
    AND P.BATCHID is NULL
    ORDER BY P.PROCESSEDTIMESTAMP ASC

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a confusing join statement. I would use `not exists` like this:

```
select *
from Parent as p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from Items
    where FK = p.ID
    and TIMESTAMP  > ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()* 1000) - p.EXPIRE)
    )
```

Comment: thanks this steered me in the right direction - end result in the edits

Comment: You got it, also you can get rid of the order by in the sub-select. It has no effect and will make your query faster.